# Measure distance between UI elements in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, storyboard, xcode10

I've updated to Xcode 10. It is awesome, but there is just one problem for me: in Xcode for measuring distance between UI elements you just needed to press ***option*** button, but now it's not working.

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: I checked again, out of many attempts worked only once...

Comment: Well, I’m suggesting it’s just you.  File a bug with Apple if you like.

Comment: The bug was gone after MacOS updating....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce. Select a subview, hold Option, hover the mouse off the subview, measurements appear. Works in Xcode 10 exactly as in the past.

[image]

Perhaps you're making the gesture incorrectly?

Comment: I used it before, I know how to do that, but now it isn't works for me.... Anyway, thank you!